# Split CMake generator expression into function arguments

Tags: cmake

I have the following CMake segment to copy some DLLs I require into the output folder of my executable:

```
file(GLOB Debug_DLLS "${SDK_DIR}/Libs/*.dll")
file(GLOB Release_DLLS "${SDK_DIR}/Libsr/*.dll")

add_custom_command(TARGET myApp POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${Debug_DLLS}>
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:${Release_DLLS}>
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:myApp>
)
```

copy_if_different is supposed to support multiple arguments.

I am 100% sure that SDK_DIR is a valid folder and also that the Release_DLLS and Debug_DLLS variable is valid. The code works if I just put in a simple filepath into Release_DLLs.

But when building I simply get the error: "The system cannot find the provided path" in my native system language. Why isn't this working with multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to quote the generator expressions and add COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS to the command.
The following code works and is probably the most flexible solution to copy different DLLs to the output directory based on the build type:

```
file(GLOB Debug_DLLS "${SDK_DIR}/Libs/*.dll")
file(GLOB Release_DLLS "${SDK_DIR}/Libsr/*.dll")

add_custom_command(TARGET myApp POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${Debug_DLLS}>"
    "$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:${Release_DLLS}>"
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:myApp>
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```